# Extracting comment at the end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have to extract tokens from the input string as well as an optional comment at the end. I have the following code and was thinking if there is a better alternative.

```js
const RE  = /([A-Z]{2,13})/g;
let input  = 'LQ, SAMOSA, LF "Hello"';
let input2 = 'LQ, SAMOSA, LF';
let input3 = 'LQ, SAMOSA "Hello", LF';
var match = RE.exec(input);
while (match) {
  console.log("Found", match[1], "at", match.index);
  match = RE.exec(input)
}
let comment = input.split(',').pop().match(/(".*?")/);
console.log(comment);
```

Comment: Better how? Is this code doing what you want?

Comment: You might want to tell us more about your input format.

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/Fb1nQS/1

Comment: Better to explain what your code is doing; there are no comments to help us. If you're thinking there may be some better way of doing it, it's more important for us to know the desired result.